# Evaluation of a recursive function's time complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, list, time-complexity

#### What I want

I am trying to find the time complexity of a function.

> **Evaluate the complexity for each step of the algorithm as well as the complexity for the entire function.**
>
> ```
> 1 def deep_copy(ls):
> 2     new=[]
> 3     for e in ls:
> 4         if type(e) == list:
> 5             new.append(deep_copy(e))
> 6         else:
> 7             new.append(e)
> 8     return new
> ```

#### What I have tried

- I know that lines 2, 4, 6 and 8 are all `O(1)`.
- The best case scenario would be that the list being copied only has simple elements (no lists within lists, if you will).

  If that is the case then line 7 has a max complexity of `O(n)` making the line 3 `for` loop have a complexity of `O(n·n) = O(n²)`. Thus the entire function would be `O(n²)` for a list with `n` simple elements.
- Now, lets say we have a list of `n` lists each with `n` elements. With the results from before, I know that line 5 is `O(n³)` since it is an `O(n²)` nested within a `O(n)`. Line 3 would be `O(n⁴)` since line 5 is executed `n` times, making the overall complexity `O(n⁴)` for this case.
- For a list of `n` lists of `n` lists each with `n` elements, line 5 would be `O(n⁵)` so then the entire loop and function would be `O(n⁶)`.

#### What the problem is

**It's clear to me that the complexity is dependent not only on the length of the lists but also, for lack of a better word, the list's depth.**

I would say that this function has a complexity of `O(n^(2·k))` with `k` being the depth.
For a simple list, `k = 1`; for a list of simple lists, `k = 2`; etc.

Is this analysis correct? If not, what is wrong with it and what is the correct answer?

Comment: You are a bit confused about what causes recursive functions to have high time complexity. I suggest to talk to your teacher.

Comment: unfortunately, that is no longer possible. would you have any insight on where I can read up on it?

Comment: @SydM107 What do you mean by "that is *no longer possible*"?

Comment: would this not have a better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @olly_uk I'd say it's a better fit here because it involves code and thus isn't theoretical. It's probably valid on either. The close-voters are misguided in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You're slightly mislead by a bad (aka. "not useful") definition of `n`. Further, you seem to assume `append` is amortized `O(n)`. It is not; it is amortized `O(1)`.

Consider the operation taking time `T(l)` on a list `l`.

```
new=[]
for e in ls:
    if type(e) == list:
        new.append(deep_copy(e))
    else:
        new.append(e)
return new
```

is

```
O(1) +                     [O(1) assign]
O(len(l)) * (              [len(l) loops + O(1) overhead for each loop]
    (O(1) +                [O(1) if]
        O(1) + T(lᵢ)) or   [O(1) append and T(lᵢ) recursion]
    (O(1) +                [O(1) else]
        O(1))              [O(1) append]
) + O(1)                   [O(1) return]
```

which is just

```
T(l) = O(len(l)) * [T(lᵢ) or O(1)] + O(1)
```

Note that because `T(lᵢ) or O(1)` depends *both* on the type of `lᵢ` *and* on `i`, we can't just solve this recursion like normal.

---

We have that our recursion works on non-square and even non-rectangular arrays. This means we can't just parameterize it in `n` with `n` the length of a list.

Instead we can parameterize it in different quantities.

We have that the recursion will traverse `N` elements in total. This means that we'll have something like

```
[
    T(l₁) +
    T(l₂) +
    T(l₃) +
    T(l₄) +
    ...
] + O(1)
```

which is just

```
[
    [T(l₁₁) + T(l₁₂) + T(l₁₃) + T(l₁₄) + ... + O(1)] +
    [T(l₂₁) + T(l₂₂) + T(l₂₃) + T(l₂₄) + ... + O(1)] +
    [T(l₃₁) + T(l₃₂) + T(l₃₃) + T(l₃₄) + ... + O(1)] +
    [T(l₄₁) + T(l₄₂) + T(l₄₃) + T(l₄₄) + ... + O(1)] +
    ...
] + O(1)
```

which is

```
[
    [T(l₁₁) + T(l₁₂) + T(l₁₃) + T(l₁₄) + ...] +
    [T(l₂₁) + T(l₂₂) + T(l₂₃) + T(l₂₄) + ...] +
    [T(l₃₁) + T(l₃₂) + T(l₃₃) + T(l₃₄) + ...] +
    [T(l₄₁) + T(l₄₂) + T(l₄₃) + T(l₄₄) + ...] +
    ...
] + O(1) + T(len(l))
```

which is, recursively unwinding,

```
[
    [[[[...[O(1) + O(1) + ...]...]]]] +
    [[[[...[...]...]]]] +
    [[[[...[...]...]]]] +
    [[[[...[...]...]]]] +
    ...
] + O(1) + O(len(l)) +
  + O(len(l₁)) + ... + O(len(l₄)) + ... +
  + O(len(l₁₁) + ... + O(len(l₄₄)) + ... +
  + O(len(l₁₁₁) + ...
  + ...
```

The first part (in `[]`s) adds to `O(N)`. The second is the *sum* of the length of the lists.

Obviously the sum of the length of the lists is at least as big as the number of base-level-items in total. We can't have *just* the number of base-level-items as the answer, though, as

```
[[[...[[[[1]]]...]]]
```

will take quite a while to be copied but only has one item.

---

So our answer is

```
O(sum(number of items in each list, including all sublists))
```

So why not parameterize in `n` or `N` or something? Why just a box of text?

Well, that's because that's all you need, and all you can give. If you have another definition, like:

> The array is of dimensions `(x₁, x₂, x₃, ..., xₙ)`.

you can *then* solve in terms of variables (`O(Σx + Πx)`). But that's not what the question gave.

---

Note that `O(nⁱ⁺¹)`, as has been previously suggested, isn't quite right for something of dimension `(n, n, n, ..., n)` with `i` dimensions. It should be `O(nⁱ + i)` instead.

---

Now, I did do something very odd. I didn't write `O(nⁱ + i)` = `O(nⁱ)`.

When you have two variables it's often (but not always) worth considering cases where *only one* is large. Normally `O(nⁱ) > O(i)`, but if you can have any `n` and `i` then `let n = 1` and `O(nⁱ) < O(i)`.

Basically, `O(nⁱ + i) = O(nⁱ)` **if and only if you want it to**. If the case `n = 1`, `i large` is important, include the `+ i`. Otherwise, don't.

---

We can quickly test that the power is `i`, not `i+1` by setting `i=1` and timing:

```
SETUP="
def deep_copy(ls):
    new=[]
    for e in ls:
        if type(e) == list:
            new.append(deep_copy(e))
        else:
            new.append(e)
    return new
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" -s "x = [0] * 10**5" "deep_copy(x)"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" -s "x = [0] * 10**6" "deep_copy(x)"
```

Gives

```
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 209 msec per loop
```

A factor of 10 increase in time spent as the length is increased by 10 implies linear cost, as I said.

Comment: Nice catch with the append being O(1). The complexity I gave was based on append being O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the function with line numbers for reference. Also, thanks to @Veedrac for pointing out that append is O(1) in Python.

```
1 def deep_copy(ls):
2     new=[]
3     for e in ls:
4         if type(e) == list:
5             new.append(deep_copy(e))
6         else:
7             new.append(e)
8     return new
```

Like you said, lines 2, 4, 6, and 8 are all O(1). Line 7 is O(1), and line 3 is O(n)*(big Oh of a loop iteration). So the question is the time complexity of line 5.

Line 5 is roughly equivalent to:

```
_ = deep_copy(e)
new.append(_)
```

What is the time complexity of this? It is the time complexity of `deep_copy(e)` *plus* the time complexity of appending - O(1). If `e` does not contain any lists, the time complexity of line 5 will be O(n), leading to the function as a whole being O(n^2). So instead of the time complexity being O(n^(2*k)), it should be O(n^k).

However, so far n has been used to mean the length of the lists. What if we use n to represent the total number of elements in all the lists? I haven't gone through and determined what the time complexity is based on the total number of elements, but it should be worth looking into.

**EDIT**:
I updated my calculations to reflect append having O(1). Also, @Veedrac showed that I was correct in thinking that having n mean the total number of elements would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, assume you instead had

```
def deep_copy(ls):
    new=[]
    for e in ls:
        if type(e) == list:
            new = new + [deep_copy(e)]
        else:
            new = new + [e]
    return new
```

`new = new + [...]` **is** `O(n)`. So what's actually the time complexity of that?

Taking the result from my other answer,

```
T(l) = O(len(l)) * [T(lᵢ) or O(1)] + O(1)
```

we have that the cost of each path **inside** the `[]`s have an extra `O(len(l))`.

```
T(l) = O(len(l)) * [T(lᵢ) + O(len(l)) or O(1) + O(len(l))] + O(1)
     = O(len(l)) * [(T(lᵢ) or O(1)) + O(len(l))] + O(1)
```

but by expanding the bracket we just have:

```
T(l) = O(len(l)) * [T(lᵢ) or O(1)] + O(len(l))·O(len(l)) + O(1)
     = O(len(l)) * [T(lᵢ) or O(1)] + O(len(l)²)
```

This means that our cost is

```
O(sum(square of number of items in each list, including all sublists))
```

So for something of dimension `(n, n, n, ..., n)` with `i` dimensions we have

```
O(
    n² +            first level; one list of length n
    n · n² +        second level; n lists of length n
    n · n · n² +    third level; n² lists of length n
    ... +
    nⁱ⁻¹ · n²         "i"th level; nⁱ⁻¹ lists of length n
)
```

which is

```
O(Σn^k from k=0 to k=i-1) · O(n²) + 
= O(nⁱ⁺¹ + i) = O(nⁱ⁺¹) as i+1 ≥ 2
```

which, unsurprisingly, is what Rob Watts had when he went with `O(n)` appends.